# vertical lines in jquery file tree

Tags: jquery, tree

Is there any way we could implement vertical lines in a jquery file tree?

Comment: Other than with an image, using left or right-only borders on a DIV, suitably positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should think using CSS you'd be able to, as jQuery File Tree puts everything in a container with a class and then further classifies the items in the tree. E.g., with rules along the lines of:

```
.jqueryFileTree .directory, .jqueryFileTree .file {
    border-left: 1px black;
}
```

That's obviously just a very crude start, but you get the idea. It targets any element with the class "directory" or "file" that's a descendant of an element with the class "jqueryFileTree" (the class on the overall container). You might use borders as above, or background images, etc. There are other classes, such as "expanded" for expanded directories, etc.

There's information about styling the file tree [on the project page](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#styling), although all it really says is that it uses CSS and you should look at the `jqueryFileTree.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

i done it myself in [jtree](http://jtree.tk) using css3 multiple background

```
ul.jtree ul li {
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : 0 8px, 0 0;
    background-size : 8px 1px, 1px 100%;
    background-image : url(img/icons/dot.png), url(img/icons/dot.png);
    padding:0;margin:0;
    line-height:20px;
}

ul.jtree ul li:last-child { background-size : 8px 1px, 1px 8px; }
```